# Make javascript injection to web view in android and get HTML to a string

Tags: android, android-webview

I have tried for a long time now to find a way to get the HTML content from a Web View which i load up in an android application. I have found several guides stating that i need to use a javascript interface and to some extent i have made that work. The problem now is that i can't get the final step done where i actually get a String of the HTML which i can manipulate with. I need a String where i can play with the html in the java code after i have retrieved it from the Web View. Here is my code so far:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //login button
        Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        final WebView webview = (WebView)(findViewById(R.id.webview));

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call private method

                webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        /* This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading. */
                        webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
                        webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                });

                webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                MyJavaScriptInterface JSInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface();

                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webview.postUrl(url, SAMLreq.getBytes());

                webview.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface, "HTMLOUT");
                //The html from the webview should be stored here
                String htmlFromWebView = JSInterface.getTheHTMLToGo();


    class MyJavaScriptInterface {

        private String theHTMLToGo = null;

        public String getTheHTMLToGo() {
            return theHTMLToGo;
        }

        public void setTheHTMLToGo(String theHTMLToGo) {
            this.theHTMLToGo = theHTMLToGo;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void processHTML(String html) {
          theHTMLToGo = html



        }
    }
}
```

I can see when i debug that the 'html' String in the javascript method called 'processHTML' actually contains the right value, but i still can't figure out how to get it out from there.

Comment: Are you seeing that html data in `processHTML(...)` method, right? You are calling `getTheHTMLToGo()` function immediately after loading. You have to wait a little to get result or you can do what you want in `processHTML(..)` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was right in front of me the whole time. As it has also been commented on my post on this question: I am basically doing the right thing. My problem is that i call the method `getTheHTMLToGo()`too soon. I moved some code into the `processHTML(String html)` and made sure that the flow completed before i went on.  I did this by calling the next thing i needed to do from within the `processHTML(String html)` method.